# The SDK platform-tools version (26.0.2) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 27

Tags: android, lint, platform-tools

my lint fails with:

```
 The SDK platform-tools version (26.0.2) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 27; please update
```

but as far as I see 26.0.2 is still the latest platform-tools:

```
⋊> ~ sdkmanager --list | grep platform | grep tools                                                                14:32:26
Warning: Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19')
Warning: Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-10' in inconsistent location '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-10' (Expected '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-10')
Warning: Observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/temp/ExtraPackage.old01' (Expected '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository')
Warning: Already observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository'. Skipping duplicate at '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/temp/ExtraPackage.old01'
Warning: Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19')
Warning: Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-10' in inconsistent location '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-10' (Expected '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-10')
Warning: Observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/temp/ExtraPackage.old01' (Expected '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository')
Warning: Already observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository'. Skipping duplicate at '/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/temp/ExtraPackage.old01'
Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.MalformedURLException]
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
  platform-tools                                                                           | 26.0.2  | Android SDK Platform-Tools                          | platform-tools/                                                                          
  platform-tools                                                                           | 26.0.2       | Android SDK Platform-Tools
```

Comment: There's a `27.0.0` available, at least from the Android Studio SDK Manager, as I have it installed.

Comment: thanks for the info - but I do not really have Android Studio on my ci-server

Comment: hm also strange 26.0.2 is the latest one here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

Comment: As it turns out, I have `27.0.0` of `build-tools`, and the Android Studio SDK Manager has `26.0.2` as the latest `platform-tools` as well. My apologies for my confusion. I'm not sure what that error is complaining about. Are you using `buildToolsVersion `27.0.0`?

Comment: yes I am getting the error using buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"

Comment: Found any solution? I am getting the same error

Comment: @ligi I posted my answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to update the gradle classpath to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'` and the gradle wrapper to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Comment: Thanks - that might be the solution - unfortunately I cannot yet use 3.0.0 as It produces a load of other problems for me - I wait until these bugs are fixed and then try out 3.0.0 - will accept this answer when I could verify that it works.

Comment: I've given the same answer. So, what's the issue here? why is lint error complaining about the platform-tools version instead of Gradle android plugin?

Comment: Not sure - I also found it confusing - hence the question here - thanks for your answer also - but mrNiceGuy was a bit faster so I will accept his answer once I can verify it works

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I changed the Android Gradle Plugin version from 2.3.3 to 3.0.1 and it worked (no longer lint error). In the sample GitHub project, it has 2.3.3 which is causing the same error. Comment that line and uncomment line number 10.
[Change](https://github.com/saurabhkpatel/SampleAndroidProject27/blob/master/build.gradle#L11)

Check more details: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69573867#comment3
https://github.com/saurabhkpatel/SampleAndroidProject27